# Possible to put header-{your_custom_template}.php in subdirectory?

Tags: themes, customization

I just learned that it is possible to create differtent header.php files in your theme by creating a new File and calling it something like:  header-myname.php.

To call, i would use the header templates tag like this:

```
get_header( 'myname' );
```

But that way I would have to put my file in the main directory of my theme, am I right?

So my question is: 
Is there a way to put the custom-header file into a sub-directory and if so, how to i declare its position with the get_header() tag ?

Comment: Is there a problem this solves? Or is this a case of the theme folder feels bloated/full? WP expects header files like that in the theme folder, what you ask for isn't possible, see the answers for why

Answer (score 4):

Not with `get_header()`, no. As you can see in [the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/#source) of `get_header()` the argument is simply appended to the filename and searched for in the root theme directory:

```
$name = (string) $name;
if ( '' !== $name ) {
    $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";
}

$templates[] = 'header.php';

locate_template( $templates, true );
```

And as far as I can tell there are no filters that would be useful here. As [Justin Tadlock noted](https://twitter.com/justintadlock/status/977962996063490048), this lack of filters has persisted for 8 years.

The next best thing you could do is to use `get_template_part()` instead:

```
get_template_part( 'subdirectory/header', 'myname' );
```

But you'll need your regular header in the subdirectory too.

The only thing you'll miss out on doing it this way is that the `get_header()` hook won't fire. But you could remedy that by putting it at the beginning of your custom template:

```
do_action( 'get_header' );
```

or for the custom template:

```
do_action( 'get_header', 'myname' );
```

But honestly, I'm not sure how widely used that hook is, because it's not very useful. You can probably get away with leaving it out.

Answer (score 3):

No. The function adds a string of `"header-{$name}.php"` to the search for templates. You can't prepend it.

However, if you're not reyling on the `get_header` action, you can just as well use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), as these functions work very similar.

```
get_template_part('subdir/header', 'my');
```

will look for a file in **subdir/header-my.php**.

Comment: so there is no need to use get_header, or get_footer in my index.php file for example. I can just use get_template_part instead? Or does it work any different ?

Comment: It works very similar. The only difference, as Jacob Peattie pointed out in more detail, is that `get_header()` calls the action `get_header`, which `get_template_part()` does not by default. You can call the action in the PHP file or leave it be, depending on your other plugins/themes